# Is it possible to download an artifact from ADO's artifact feed through the browser?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have a ADO build pipeline that creates build artifacts and publishes them to an artifact feed.

To download these artifacts, the documentation points to using an Azure CLI.

In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73161790/cannot-download-artifact-in-azure-devops), an answer points to downloading from the pipeline results.

Is there anyway to download the artifact from the artifact feed from the browser, without configuring a CLI?

If not, is there any documented reason why this functionality is unavailable?

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear statement on why this is not available. Here is feature request to open API for direct package download from universal artifact and to provide simple "download" button when accessing through browser: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/download-universal-package-trough-api/495533#T-N1649230

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking about downloading manually any artefacts from a build pipeline?

If so have you noticed this cunningly disguised link?

[image]

Comment: Aware of downloading from pipelines, I want to enable users to download from the artifact feed without having to navigate to the build pipelines.